# how to java set the PATH of my Debian 7.3 system ?to link the java version I want

Tags: linux, debian

If I insert into the terminal:

```
aryan@localhost:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.5) (6b27-1.12.5-1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: If that is the java version you want, it is already in the PATH. Its location can be found using `which java`

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please add some explicit question in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Debian is using the "alternatives system" to handle different versions of the same command. Have a look at `man update-alternatives` or install `galternatives` to configure the default version of java.

If you type `which java` it will always print `/usr/bin/java`. however this will only be a link to the alternatives system which will link to the chosen version.

The available java versions are usually located under `/usr/lib/jvm/`. But you can also download some java and extract it to your home directory if you like.
Usually java applications only need to know the correct `$JAVA_HOME` and everything is fine.